# An estimate of harmonic function

Tags: sobolev-spaces, linear-pde

I encounter the following estimate in several situations, but cannot see how to prove it. Could anyone show me how?

> If $u$ is a harmonic fuction on a domian $\Omega$ with smooth boundary, then 
>   $$\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\leq C\|u\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}.
> $$
>   where $C$ is some constant independent of $u$

Edit: Thanks you, Michał Miśkiewicz, for your answer. Although, I am still curious about whether this estimate can be derived without the use of inverse trace theorem.

Comment: With any luck someone who knows something will explain. Meanwhile, you might note that if $\Omega$ is the unit disk in the plane you can give a simple proof using the Fourier series of the boundary function.

Comment: @Ullrich Oh， thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use two propositions:

**1.** $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ is the trace space of $H^1(\Omega)$, meaning that the trace operator $H^1(\Omega) \to H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ is continuous and onto. For each $v \in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ there is $w \in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $w = v$ on $\partial \Omega$ and 
\begin{equation}
\label{eq}
\tag{$\star$}
\| w \|_{H^1(\Omega)} \le C \| v \|_{H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)}.
\end{equation}

**2.** Harmonic functions are minimizers of the Dirichlet energy. That is, if $v \in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$, then the unique solution of 
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u = 0 & \text{ in } \Omega, \\
u = v & \text{ on } \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
is at the same time the unique minimizer of $\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2$ in the class of $H^1(\Omega)$-functions equal to $v$ on $\partial \Omega$.

---

Taking $v = u|_{\partial \Omega}$ and choosing some $w \in H^1(\Omega)$ as in **1**, we can compare 
$$ \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 \le \int_{\Omega} |\nabla w|^2 $$
according to **2**. Since $u-w \in H_0^1(\Omega)$, Poincare's inequality yields 
\begin{align*}
\| u \|_{L^2(\Omega)} - \| w \|_{L^2(\Omega)} & \le \| u-w \|_{L^2(\Omega)} \\
& \le C \| \nabla u - \nabla w \|_{L^2(\Omega)} \\
& \le 2 C \| \nabla w \|_{L^2(\Omega)}.
\end{align*}
Thus, the estimate \eqref{eq} is valid also for $u$, possibly with a larger constant.